# Check if a Facebook user likes a page using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I want to check whether the loggedIn user has liked a specified page or not. Below is my code.

```
$fql_pageid = "SELECT url,site,id FROM object_url WHERE url    
                     IN('http://developers.facebook.com/')";
$api_pageid = $facebook->api(array(
                    'method' => 'fql.query',
                    'query' => $fql_pageid
));
$pageid = $api_pageid[0]["id"]; //get id of the specified page
$fql_like = 'SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()';
$api_like = $facebook->api(array(
                    'method' => 'fql.query',
                    'query' => $fql_like
));
```

When I do `var_dump($api_like)`, there are only 6 records appearing. But I checked my Facebook account, there are 22 likes.

Anyone knows what's wrong the above code? Or is there any other way to check whether a user has liked a specified page?

Comment: like count is a sum of a few things, like shares, likes, etc.  So maybe there were more shares of your site than likes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's say that you want to check if the current user (*uid=me()*) is Fan of the "Big Bang Theory" page with *page_id=22934684677* (http://graph.facebook.com/TheBigBangTheory) you should run this query:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=22934684677
```

Answer (score 2):

If instead you want to see if the current user likes a website:

```
SELECT user_id FROM url_like WHERE url='http://someurl.com' AND user_id=me()
```

This is useful for page tab apps where normal like buttons will only like the page the tab resides in.